# Spark Multiple file processing

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have multiple Java processes. Each processes will generate a data files which will be periodically containing new data.

I need Spark to read these files and dump the data in database. 
I have following questions with respect to above requirement -

1. Is there any way Spark can know that it has processed 1000 records and have to start from 1001 each time it picks the file for processing?
2. Or do I have to purge the file once Spark processes it 1000 records and each time the file should contain only unprocessed records. In this case how can I read and write the records in the same file.

Since I have continuous generation of data, I cannot wait for Spark to complete its job and then allow the file to be loaded with new data.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your problem i think you should use Spark Streaming and specify HDFS/S3, Kafka or flume as your source.

Best way would be to change you Java Processes to publish the records in Kafka and write a spark streaming code to read these records.

You can read more details here :-

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

If this is not possible, One thing you can do is to check the last modified date of each file and read only those files whose last modified date is less than 2minutes from current time. If the current date time is 06/15/2017 8:00 AM You need to make sure that your code is reading only those files which have last modified date less than 06/15/2017 07:58 AM. This way you make sure that you are only reading those files which are not being processed by the Java processes. i.e in which you are currently not appending new data.

You would only read those files in which there has been no activity for last 2 minutes. The time gap of 2 minutes is changeable and you can change this as per your code logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, considering the logic of using reading file based on last modified timestamp will not solve my requirement of reaching to the record in the file which should be processed.

One approach i found was using Java 1.7 introduced SeekableByteChannel using which you can track the position in the file at which you are writing the new records and pass it to the Spark layer. Spark can then read records from that position and process it.

Comment: I am assuming that you would be reading a file only once. If that is true then you dont need to read a file from a specific position. You would read that file only if the process has stopped writing into it.

Comment: Are you reading these files from HDFS? Can you use flume and spark streaming?

Comment: No, I have some limitations because of which i cannot integrate my processes through Kafka.. Using spark streaming is secondary thing.. I dont think i need to use since i can read the file using Spark RDD APIs.  As i said this file will be continuously getting new data and my Spark program has to read new data from the same file continuously